# MYSQL 5.7 installation on AIX 7.1

Tags: mysql, aix, database-administration, mysql-5.7

appreciate your support to guide me which package should i use to install mysql5.7 on AIX 7.1 as i can't find build for aix .

```
./mysqld --initialize --user=mysql
```

when i used generic linux package i got below error:

```
*bash: ./mysqld: cannot execute binary file*
```

and also i can't  build from source so if you required steps for building from source this will be much helpful .

```
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found
```

Comment: Sadly, mysql uses CMake and C++ -- both of them are very problematic on exotic platforms like AIX

Comment: Do you need exactly this version? What about MariaDB?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes i need mysql 5.7 to be DR server for another mysql 5.7 running on windows VM .

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond do you have any suggestions how to use them or which mysql build can be installed on AIX instead of source code ?

Comment: I really don't think you could do that :(